# Conditional sum in SQL (SAS) (SUMIFS equivalent)

Tags: sql, sas, sumifs

Let say I am working under SAS EG and I have 2 tables:

Table1:

```
Id  Item
1   A
1   B
1   C
2   B
2   D
3   C
3   E
3   F
```

Table2:

```
Id  Item    Amount
1   A   99
2   C   100
1   B   100
2   A   90
1   A   93
3   B   92
1   E   93
2   B   99
1   A   93
```

Now I would like to take the sum conditional for my table1 from table2 (when the ID and the Item match).

```
Id  Item    Want
1   A   285
1   B   100
1   C   0
2   B   99
2   D   0
3   C   0
3   E   0
3   F   0
```

So what am I supposed to do in SQL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd try a correlated subquery.

Comment: Can you explain in detail?

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing?  What does `sum conditional` mean?  Are you just asking to group by ID and ITEM?

Answer (score 1):

Use a *correlated subquery* to SUM:

```
select t1.Id, t1.Item,
       (select sum(t2.amount) from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id and t2.item = t1.item)
from table1 t1
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like aggregation to me, with a `left join`:

```
select t1.id, t1.item,
       coalesce(sum(t2.amount), 0) as want
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t2.item = t2.item
group by t1.id, t1.item;
```